# agregation subqueries in slick

Tags: subquery, slick

I want to use slick-way to subqueries like this:

```
   select suppliers.*, 
          (select count(1) from cofees 
            where cofees.sup_id == suppliers.sup_id 
          ) 
     from suppliers
```

and map one to type `Seq[(Supplier, Int)]`

and also similar request

```
   select suppliers.*
    where cofees.sup_id == suppliers.id) 
     from suppliers where not exists (select 1 from cofees 
            where cofees.sup_id == suppliers.sup_id)
```

I found only plain-sql way:

```
   db.run {sql"""select sup_id, name
    where cofees.sup_id == suppliers.id) 
     from suppliers where not exists (select 1 from cofees 
            where cofees.sup_id == suppliers.sup_id)
   """}
```

but I want something like

```
db.run{ 
  for {
    s <- suppliers
    c <- counts(???)
  } yield( s, c)
}
```

```
db.run{
  for {
   s <- suppliers if not exists (???)
  } yield(s) 
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first one should work like this - use a left join to also get zero coffees (if that's what you wanted)

```
  for {
    (s, c) <- suppliers joinLeft coffees on (_.sup_id===_.id)
  } yield(s, c)
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .map { case (s, c) => (s, c.length) }
```

for second, guess you can add `if c.length === 0`

Edited as per Adel's suggestion - it was missing a `groupBy`

Comment: thank you. I'll try ones ASAP ad then mark you cuestion

Comment: it isn't worked, but if add groupBy - worked fine. Thank you for idea. If you edit answer, I will mark one as valid. `val q = (for {
      (s, c) <- suppliers joinLeft coffees on (_.sup_id===_.id)
    } yield(s, c)).groupBy(_._1)
    val q2 = q.map { case (s, c) =>
      (s, c.length)
    }`

Comment: hm, not sure why the groupBy kicks out the rows without c (for count count=0)